# Swipe to open expand a View, on an Activity containing a navigation menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, swipe-gesture

I've implemented a keyboard on an android app, and the app also has a navigation drawer.

The result im trying to achieve is something like what they have on a [google calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calculator&hl=en), where that green rectangle with an arrow on the right , can be open with a click, or a swipe

[image]

Can someone give me some pointers how to do this, considering that the navigation drawer already have swipe to open and close

Thank you

Comment: Take that as imageview and than on clicking that replace fragment

Comment: or https://github.com/rahulparsani/material-calculator